# Applying SSL on the localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl

[image]I am applying SSL in my sample web application using self signed certificate. The purpose is to test the session availability when I go from http to https or the other way round.
My localhost address is localhost:5366. I have done these as follows:

I have added a website in IIS. But confused that when binding using http, I give port 5366. I works fine but when I remove it and apply https, port 5366. The page doesnot load.

So, what should I do to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you get any error msg? like a 404?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit confusing, but if i can bet, you are interchanging the debug mode from VS and the published site, correct me if am wrong.
I configured my https site in this way:

1. Configure your IIS to accept https through port 443.
2. Set the website file system place to a certain folder
3. Publish your website with VS to this folder
4. Reach it through `https://localhost`

Hope it works!

Comment: My localhost address is 'localhost:5366' Therefore the above address will navigate to iis default page

Comment: Have you configured your sites bindings to accept https through the specified port? Dont forget you cannot use the same port to accept http and https!
Can you show me some pics of your iis config, especially the bindings?

Comment: Port for http is 80 and for https 443

Comment: Than you have to publish your site under the specified folder -> overwrite the iis default page.
For example my sites phisical path is C:\MySslSite, under this folder i have an index.html. In IIS->Web Sites->MySslSite->Right Click->Properties->Physical path -> C:\MySslSite
And after this i can reach it with my browser with https://localhost

Answer (score 0):

My project was not residing in the iis physical path. Therefore, it was not loading my desired pages. Thank you guys.